# viewpager screen swiped to right or left?

Tags: android

How do i know if the user swiped a screen on right or left in a view pager ?

```
indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected (int page)
    {
        //page changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled (int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged (int arg0)
    {
    }
});
```

I used this method and i am pretty sure the onpagescrollstatechanged is the one to tell us if its right or left but how do we use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save value separately in another variable and compare it onpagescrollstate.

```
OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(savePosition>arg0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swiped Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swiped Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    savePosition = arg0;
                }
            };
```

Answer (score 4):

Try that:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    if(lastPage>arg0)
      {//User Move to left}
    else(lastPage<arg0) 
     {//User Move to right}
      lastPage=arg0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This is my solution in the ***onPageScrolled()*** method of ***ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener*** :
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the user is scrolling left or right real-time. You can do something like this:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        float tempPositionOffset = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (position == 0) {
                if (tempPositionOffset < positionOffset) {
                    Log.d("eric", "scrolling left ...");
                } else {
                    Log.d("eric", "scrolling right ...");
                }

                tempPositionOffset = positionOffset;

          Log.d("eric", "position " + position + "; " + " positionOffset " + positionOffset + "; " + " positionOffsetPixels " + positionOffsetPixels + ";");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```